# cannot use some certain subdomain for firebase dynamic link

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am quite new to firebase dynamic links, I was trying to create a firebase dynamic link with a subdomain let's say: `apple.page.link`, but then it showed an error this subdomain cannot be used by anyone? So what does that mean, are there some certain types of subdomain only that I can use? Do I need to have my own website to create firebase dynamic links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a subdomain, you need to verify the root domain first.

Please refer to the Firebase Subdomain official documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/hosting/dns/subdomain

Comment: then, how does this automatically verify the subdomain? without asking me for any additional verification process?